# How can I split a string with batch commands in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an LED sign set up with a Windows computer, and am trying to make it display my Linux computer's temperature:

acpitz-virtual-0

Adapter: Virtual device

temp1:       +97.7Â°F  (crit = +183.2Â°F)

Now, here's the batch file on my computer

```
wget 192.168.1.58/sensor1.txt
```

I have a windows version of wget in the folder.

```
type sensor1.txt | findstr /v acpitz-virtual-0 | findstr /v Adapter: > msg.txt
set /p msg= < msg.txt

prismcom.exe usb {HOLD} %msg%
```

Now my sign flashes the equivalent of

temp1:       +97.7Â°F  (crit = +183.2Â°F)

I need it to flash

+97.7Â°F,

or even better,

+97.7 F

I've been trying with FIND and FOR and commands like that, but with no luck. How can I modify my string to work?

Thanks!

Comment: "trying with find and for and stuff like that"? I have to remember that for my next technical question (or better yet, interview question answer). I wonder how it would go... "How would you design a linked list?" - "Well, I'd use pointers and nodes and stuff like that and make it work.". Yep - that would do it. BAM! New job with big pay!! :-)

Comment: Ahem.
Correction:
I've been trying with FIND and FOR and commands like that, but with no luck.

Comment: Oh, yes - your correction is much more precise. ;-) 'I'd use "pointers" and "nodes" and stuff like that' is much clearer.

Comment: Thanks. Can you answer the question too?

Comment: Sure. :-) Use `FOR` with `tokens=` and stuff, and figure out what you can use for `tokens` to break up the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say the variable that the temperature is stored in is called "temp", and has the value of "temp1: +97.7Â°F (crit = +183.2Â°F)". This little snippet should work wonders...

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set dis=!temp:~7,5! F
set check=!temp:~10,1!
if %check% neq . set dis=!temp:~7,6! F
```

Here is the syntax:

```
set variable=!variable_to_be_constrained:~offset,amount_of_characters!
```

One thing I should mention is that the variable "TEMP" (or "temp", capitalization generally doesn't matter too much with .bat files) is a predefined command line variable, and generally those should never be overwritten. However, in this case it's purely for aesthetic purposes and you can change it to whatever you want.

--EDIT--
Added two lines to allow for temperatures over 100 Fahrenheit. Also changed `temp` to `dis`.

Comment: +1, But what you do when the temperature is higher than 100.0°F?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows version of wget, then you might as well also have a special command to parse the temperature.  In C you can easily do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[1000];
    scanf("temp1: %[+0-9.]", buf);
    printf("%sF", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this with any C compiler.  Obtain a free one from [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) (preferred because the compiled code won't require any extra DLLs) or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) (which does require an extra DLL).  You can also try [Microsoft Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-products), but it's more hassle.

If the code above is in `filter.c`, then the command for MinGW or Cygwin will be

```
gcc filter.c -o filter
```

This will produce a file called `filter.exe`, which you can use in your pipeline with

```
type sensor1.txt | findstr /v acpitz-virtual-0 | findstr /v Adapter: | filter > msg.txt
```

The moral is that limited tools (like `cmd.exe`) are often not worth the trouble.

Comment: Sorry, but -1. This doesn't answer the question asked, which was "How to split a string with batch commands in Windows". It might be an alternative, like "How do I fix my Honda's check engine light?" "Buy a Toyota" could be a solution. (Or "How do I write this code in C?" "You can use this in Python.") Apples and oranges.

Comment: Fair enough, but sometimes the best answer to a question is to say that the question is not the right one.  Teaching 23 years will teach you this.

Comment: Interesting question:  Who's being pedantic in this discussion?

Comment: OK. As a teacher of 23 years, please tell me: "How do you say 'What is my name' in French?". I doubt that the answer is "Well, you can say 'What's my name?" in English instead and it will work, because I've been a teacher for 20+ years and that's the better answer."

Comment: Clever, but oh come on... Software design entails judgement.  Language translation - at least at the level you have asked - absolutely does not.  If your question were about tranlating Proust we could have a serious disucssion.

Comment: Yep. You're right. My student asked a question about American history in 1776, and my answer was about solving the problem using a math equation where `1 + 7 + 7 + 6 =21`. Sometimes it requires judgement - I bow to your superior education and judgement.